# Phonegap GA plugin not working

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, google-analytics-api, phonegap-build

I am using phonegap 3.3 to build android app locally and trying to use the GA plugin

I have installed the GAplugin using

```
phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/GAPlugin.git
```

Added this code in my index.

```
var gaPlugin;

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    alert("calling ga");
    gaPlugin = window.plugins.gaPlugin;
    alert("calling init")
    gaPlugin.init(successHandler, errorHandler, "UA-48220634-1", 1);
    gaPlugin.trackPage( nativePluginResultHandler, nativePluginErrorHandler, "index.html");
    gaPlugin.trackEvent( nativePluginResultHandler, nativePluginErrorHandler, "Button", "Click", "event only", 1);
    gaPlugin.exit(nativePluginResultHandler, nativePluginErrorHandler);
}

function successHandler()
{
    alert("init success");
}

function errorHandler()
{
    alert("init failed");
}

function nativePluginResultHandler()
{
    alert("tracking success");
}

function nativePluginErrorHandler()
{
    alert("tracking failed");
}
```

I get all successful messages but cant see anything in Google Analytics.

I also tried manually including the GAPlugin.js but no change.

I can see GAPlugin in list of plugins

```
Anujs-MacBook-Pro:my-app edunewz$ phonegap plugin list
[phonegap] com.adobe.plugins.GAPlugin
[phonegap] com.jamiestarke.webviewdebug
[phonegap] org.apache.cordova.camera
[phonegap] org.apache.cordova.file
[phonegap] org.apache.cordova.file-transfer
[phonegap] org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```

Can anybody help me out.

Comment: I recently set this up with about the same code. It took awhile to get stats, and the "Real-Time" isn't working... but your code is correct.

Comment: Thanks...for now I just used the offline ga.js method. Works well. Will give this a try again.

Comment: Joe Lannen: the permissions and properly triggering events got real-time working for me. The location is for the map (forget if fine is even needed, but added for good measure.)

Comment: gaPlugin.init(successHandler, errorHandler, "UA-48220634-1", 1); you should change the 1 at the end to 10, as that's how often in seconds it sends data to google. And wastes the app users bandwidth.

Answer (score 4):

Go into /platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml and make sure

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

are present.

Execute:

```
phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/GAPlugin.git
phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information.git
phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation.git
```

I also added:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.adobe.plugins.gaplugin" />
<gap:plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager" />
<gap:plugin name="Geolocation" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker" />
```

to config.xml.

Make sure you copy + paste GAPlugin.js from /plugins/com.adobe.plugins.GAPlugin/www into your /www folder.

The code posted below comes from: https://github.com/shanabus/phonegapbuildtest/blob/master/Index.html

Most of it is just extra, as he shows working feedback in the actual app.

```
<script src="GAPlugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    //var baseUrl = 'http://grappsmobile.com/grtv/';

    $(function() {
        // on exit
        // gaPlugin.exit(nativePluginResultHandler, nativePluginErrorHandler);
    });

    var gaPlugin;
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", myDeviceReadyListener, false);

    function myDeviceReadyListener() {          
        gaPlugin = window.plugins.gaPlugin;
        gaPlugin.init(gaSuccess, gaError, "UA-23823097-4", 10);
        //23823097-4 <-- web property
        //23823097-3 <-- app property
    } 

    function gaSuccess() {
        try
        {
            gaPlugin.trackPage( nativePluginResultHandler, nativePluginErrorHandler, "index.html");
            $("#gaResults").html("<span class='success'>GA tracked pageview!</span>");
            $("#pageHome ul li a").off("click").on("click", function() {
                gaPlugin.trackPage( nativePluginResultHandler, nativePluginErrorHandler, $(this).attr("href") );
            });
        } catch (e) {
            $("#gaResults").html("<span class='error'>GA could not track pageview - " + e + "</span>");
        }
    }

    function gaError() {
        $("#gaResults").append("<span class='error'>GA error</span>");
    }

    function nativePluginResultHandler(obj) {
        $("#gaResults").append("<br /><span class='warn'>GA Plugin Result - ");
        if (obj != undefined) {
            $("#gaResults").append(obj);
        }
        $("#gaResults").append("</span>");
    }

    function nativePluginErrorHandler() {
        $("#gaResults").append("<span class='error'>GA Plugin Error Result</span>");
    }
</script>
```

Make sure you're using Mobile App Analytics, and not web analytics like he is in the above code snippet.

Observe how he is tracking these events (I learned a lot from this):
https://github.com/shanabus/phonegapbuildtest/search?q=gaPlugin.trackEvent

Use the plugin's example for how to accomplish VariableButtonClicked, PageButtonClicked, TrackButtonClicked. https://github.com/bobeast/GAPlugin/blob/master/Example/index.html The example code never worked out of the box for me, so just use it as a reference.

Check under https://www.google.com/analytics/web/?hl=en#realtime/ and pray. Sometimes it takes a long time before showing, so give it a day before you start troubleshooting. The rest of analytics data is like 24 hours behind, so select the current day if you want to see data 1-5 hours after.. sometimes longer.

Some people might say these extra steps are overkill, and they would be right.. but I had to do some combination of all of them before it worked for me. Strangely enough I feel like I'm leaving something out. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

in My Case it was network information plugin missing :

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information
```