# GAPlugin on Cordova 3.4 errors with "Class not found"

Tags: cordova, google-analytics, phonegap-plugins

This problem has been covered many times on StackOverflow but none of the solutions have worked for me.

I'm on Cordova 3.4.1-0.1.0, and I'm running the app on Android. These are my plugins:

```
[ 'com.adobe.plugins.GAPlugin',
  'com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin',
  'com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice',
  'de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification',
  'nl.x-services.plugins.calendar',
  'org.apache.cordova.device',
  'org.apache.cordova.dialogs',
  'org.apache.cordova.geolocation',
  'org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser',
  'org.apache.cordova.network-information',
  'org.apache.cordova.vibration' ]
```

In my config.xml I have the following:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
<gap:plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager" />
<gap:plugin name="Geolocation" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker" />
<gap:plugin name="com.adobe.plugins.gaplugin" />
```

I only added geolocation on the advice of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21902799/phonegap-ga-plugin-not-working) but it hasn't made a difference.

The point at which it fails is during the `.init()` - the error callback is receiving the string "Class not found". I am running .init() during the `deviceready` event handler callback.

If anybody has any ideas I'd be eternally grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had much better luck with this plugin for Google Analytics:
http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.danielcwilson.plugins.googleanalytics

Comment: Thank you! I will have a go and see if it works, I'll let you know soon hopefully.

Comment: Amazing, it works. Thank you so, so much. You are a legend. May the gods themselves adorn you and your kin with glorious wreaths and bless you with great fortune for all of eternity. Seriously, for real: Mega thanks. Hero.